# Find corresponding columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset simalar to this one:

```
p = {'A': [0,1,0,1], 'B': [1,1,1,1], 'C': [0,0,1,1], 'D': [1,1,1,0]}
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data=p)
df5
```

Now I would like to create a list with the corresponding values per row, which I was currently doing like:

```
cols = df5.dot(df5.columns).map(set).values.tolist()
cols
```

However if the name of my column is not 'A' but 'AA' than this is not working anymore, is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add separator for columns names, then remove last by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
p = {'AA': [0,1,0,1], 'B': [1,1,1,1], 'C': [0,0,1,1], 'D': [1,1,1,0]}
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data=p)

cols = df5.dot(df5.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',').map(set).values.tolist()
print (cols)
[{'D', 'B'}, {'B', 'D', 'AA'}, {'C', 'D', 'B'}, {'B', 'AA', 'C'}]
```

Another solution is use numpy indexing:

```
c = df5.columns.to_numpy()
cols = [set(c[x]) for x in df5.to_numpy().astype(bool)]
print (cols)
[{'D', 'B'}, {'B', 'D', 'AA'}, {'C', 'D', 'B'}, {'B', 'AA', 'C'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the 1 values with the column name

```
df5.replace(1, pd.Series(df5.columns, df5.columns), inplace=True)
```

Replace the 0 values with nans, then use `stack` to drop them and convert to list

```
cols = df5.replace(0, np.nan).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list).tolist()
cols
```

This returns a list of lists instead of a list of sets:

```
[['B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

The stacking is to remove the zeroes. If you are okay to keep them (and maybe remove in a different step, `df5.values.tolist()` will do.